# DJS MongoDB Only Updating First Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

When using one of my commands to update the guild document, it only updates the top guild document instead of the guild it gets sent in, Heres a picture to further explain it:

[image: explanation]

I want to make it so it updates in the guild it gets sent in, Heres what I have.

Code:

```
    run: async (interaction, client) => {

        let data = await guildSchema.findOne({
            id: interaction.guild.id
        });

      // Command:

        await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
             logChannel: interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id
        });
}
```

I have also tried:

`await data.findOneAndUpdate({`

But that just returns:

`TypeError: data.findOneAndUpdate is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
run: async (interaction, client) => {
    const data = await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
        id:interaction.guild.id \\it will search for your data
    }, 
    {
        logChannel: interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id
    };
}
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

When using `.findOneAndUpdate()`, it takes two arguments which are the filter and the value to change the document to. In your code, you are basically asking `mongoose` to search for a document where the `logChannel` is equal to `interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id` and then you are not specifying what you are updating it to. So in your case, all you have to do is add the filter and also properly receive the data because since you are using `.findOneAndUpdate`, it returns a document snapshot before it was changed. So your code might look something like this:

```js
const data = await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
    id: interaction.guild.id // Give the filter here
}, 
{
    logChannel: interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id // Update the data here
}, {
    new: true // You can optionally give this property if you want to receive the new document after the change
});
```

You can learn more about `.findOneAndUpdate()` here: [Mongoose | findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

Comment: that is not what  i am trying to accomplish, im not checking if `logChannel` is equal to `interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id` i am using that command to change `logChannel` to the  given channel in the command no matter what it is already equal to. So when running the command `/logchannel <channel>` it gets that channel id and replaces whatever is in the `logChannel` value to that ID

Comment: In your current code, you are just checking if `logChannel` is equal to the channel option in the slash command. So to fix it, you could apply a filter like I told in the answer and then it would update the proper one. You could apply a filter like this: `{ id: interaction.guild.id }`